# Terraform : wait till the dynamodb table status is "Active"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface, terraform-provider-aws

I have some terraform code that will create the dynamodb table and inserts one item into that table. When I run `terraform apply` I am getting below error. It seems it going to insert the item before the dynamodb table gets complete created (status - Active).

```
module "dynamodb_table" {
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/dynamodb-table/aws"
  name     = "${var.aws.region}-${var.config.dynamodb.table_name}"
  hash_key = var.config.dynamodb.hash_key
  attributes = [
    {
      name = var.config.dynamodb.hash_key
      type = "S"
    }
  ]
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  table_class  = "STANDARD"
}

resource "random_string" "random" {
  length  = 16
  special = false
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "table_item" {
  table_name = "${var.aws.region}-${var.config.dynamodb.table_name}"
  hash_key   = var.config.dynamodb.hash_key
  item = <<ITEM
  {
    "${var.config.dynamodb.hash_key}": {"S": "${random_string.random.result}"},
    "collections": {"M": {}}
  }
  ITEM
}
```

Error message:

```
Error: creating DynamoDB Table Item: ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found
```

Comment: Well, it might be that terraform tries to create the item in the table first, because there are no implicit dependencies between the table and the item. In this case, you might try using `depends_on` so you tell terraform to create the table prior to trying to create the item. So for example, you would add `depends_on = module.dynamodb_table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wait for the table to exist, using Terraform [`depends_on`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) should be enough to suffice:

```
module "dynamodb_table" {
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/dynamodb-table/aws"
  name     = "${var.aws.region}-${var.config.dynamodb.table_name}"
  hash_key = var.config.dynamodb.hash_key
  attributes = [
    {
      name = var.config.dynamodb.hash_key
      type = "S"
    }
  ]
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  table_class  = "STANDARD"
}

resource "random_string" "random" {
  length  = 16
  special = false
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "table_item" {
  table_name = "${var.aws.region}-${var.config.dynamodb.table_name}"
  depends_on = [module.dynamodb_table]
  hash_key   = var.config.dynamodb.hash_key
  item = <<ITEM
  {
    "${var.config.dynamodb.hash_key}": {"S": "${random_string.random.result}"},
    "collections": {"M": {}}
  }
  ITEM
}
```